# Customize own page depending on iFrame content?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to include a Spreadshirt Shop (Affiliate) on my website.
For this I would like to integrate the Creator Tool and the shopping cart, this works so far as well.
It is integrated via a Javascript as IFrame.
Now both sides have a preloader which displays the Spreadshirt logo, but I would have my visitors see my logo until the tools are loaded.
Since I do not think that this gets manipulated within the iframe, I have another idea.
I would like to create a separate DIV with z-index from the page view on it until the page is loaded in the iFrame. For this I would have to in the iFrame of the Creator Tool the DIV  and in the shopping cart the DIV  monitor and once these items are in place, disable my DIV.
Unfortunately I can only use HTMl and PHP. Can someone please help me, for example with Javascript or jQuery?

Comment: you want to remove a div on a page when an iframe of this page is loaded?

Comment: Hello, Mister Jojo. 
I want to remove the div if the iframe is finished loading.
But the preloader with the logo I didn't want to show is also in the iframe, so I think that need control if some element of the finished iframe page is there.
I hope that explain it rigth!

Comment: I read and try many now. It seams to be not posible to get an element from iframe on cross domain if you didn't have controll to the website of iframe and I didn't have any control about the website inside the iframe. The problem are note the programming language or the code, it is the security settings in all modern browsers.

Answer (score 1):

So, I think window.parent.postMessage is your key : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage

pageZ1.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Z1</title>
  <style>
    iframe{ width: 200px; height: 200px;}
    .noDisplay { display: none;}
  </style>
  </head>
<body>
  <h4>main page</h4>
  <div id="logo">LOGO</div>
  <iframe src="PageZ2.html" frameborder="0"></iframe>

  <script>
  window.onmessage=e=>{
    if (e.data==='load End') logo.className = 'noDisplay'
  }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

PageZ2.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Z2</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h6>page Z 2</h6>
  <button id="btLoadEnd">end loading event of something</button>

  <script>
    btLoadEnd.onclick=_=>{
      window.parent.postMessage('load End',"*");
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for try to help. but I need something without buttons.
Here the example of the page with the iframe https://www.mytrendy24.de/#!/create
This iframe came from external with a javascript code I get from them, so i didn't have any controll about this iframe and the thinks inside this iframe.
On load this page you see the heart Logo.
Since the page is not loaded complete I want to show my own stuff above this window, and after the load in the iframe is ready i want to hide my div.
So users that visit my page didn't see this (heart) loading logo.

Comment: @Thinkman  my button is just for example, you may replace it by a element.onload event to use the postMessage

Comment: @Thinkman In fact I have the impression that you have no idea of the technical degree that it requires and your question is completely beside the problem. In the future, avoid wasting 'my' time. for this kind of integration, ask your partner directly to create the feature that interests you

Comment: I read and try many now.
It seams to be not posible to get an element from iframe on cross domain if you didn't have controll to the website of iframe and I didn't have any control about the website inside the iframe. The problem are note the programming language or the code, it is the security settings in all modern browsers.

Comment: This time, the question is better asked. Only Spreadshirt Shop can add sending the message (postMessage) when the end of their posting occurs, and document the use on its site.